# How to Bind specific Columns of a datatable to a DataGridView?

Tags: datagridview, datatable, binding

My `DataTable` has three columns fetched from a database, while I need to bind only two columns of it to a `DataGridView`. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: asp.net winforms? please specify the framework and/or language

Answer (score 29):

Create the columns for the DataGridView yourself. Try something like this.

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Field1";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Field1";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Field2";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Field2";

bindingSource1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Answer (score 21):

Add the column as answered above, and do not forget to set:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Comment: Weirdly, AutoGenerateColumns doesn't seem to show up in intellisense for me. When I just typed in dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns=false it worked exactly as intended, but it was confusing that it didn't show up.

Comment: I followed the instructions on this question to get intellisense to work right with the datagridview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603438/incomplete-list-of-properties-methods-in-intellisense

Answer (score 3):

This was asked a while ago, so you probably won't need this answer... Hopefully others will find it useful.

I had to do something similar, and I found that the simplest solution was to create a temporary copy of the table (in which your data is stored) and then to simply remove the column in question. For example:

```
DataTable temp = YourDataTable;
temp.Columns.Remove(temp.Columns[2]) // Will remove the third column for example
YourDataTable.DataSource = temp;
YourDataTable.DataBind();
```

I think this should do the trick!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select  Fieldname1,fieldname2 from Table Name", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Clear();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  }
```

Definitely it will work.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a new DataTable with the required Columns and add rows to it from the Dataset. Then we can initialize the DataGrid with the Newly Created DataTable.

```
dt = new DataTable();          
dt_Property.Columns.Add("Field1");
dt_Property.Columns.Add("Field2");
int i = 0;
DataRow row = null;
foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{               
    row = dt.NewRow();                    
    row["Field1"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1];
    row["Field2"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2];
    dt_Property.Rows.Add(row);   
    i = i + 1;
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind DataTable to DataGridView after that hide the column you don't want.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); <-- Get data from Database here
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
DataTable resultTable = view.ToTable(false, "Column1", 
"Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5","Column6");
dataGridView.DataSource = resultTable ;
```