# My DataGrid binding collection column appears twice

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have this `View Model`:

```
public class Person
{
    public bool Selected;
    public string Name;  
    public bool IsMaried;
    public DataTime bDay;
}

List<Person> col;
```

And this is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid
    Grid.Row="1"
    Name="dataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding col}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="60" Header="Select" SortMemberPath="IsSelected">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
                        <Image/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Name"
            Binding="{Binding Name}" 
            Width="180"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have several issues:

1. In order to configure columns `Width` I added this columns inside `<DataGrid.Columns>` and now i can see my `Data Grid` columns but if I add this manually every column appears twice.
2. In my `Person` class I have another member - `DataTime` that I don't want to see inside my `DataGrid` but add `Context Menu` click and then show this Value. How can I remove it from my `DataGrid` ?

Comment: set DataGrid property AutoGeneratedColumns=false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907429/how-to-bind-specific-columns-of-a-datatable-to-a-datagridview/15828206#15828206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the  `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and add all the columns that you want to display manually. So your DataGrid could be something like this :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
            Name="dataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding col}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" Binding="{Binding Selected}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsMaried" Binding="{Binding IsMaried}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```