# Create new column in the table by accepting datepicker value as column name

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datepicker

I am trying to create WinForm accounting application using c# and Microsoft Visual Studio. I want to create a new column in the table. The column name should be fetch from the datepicker.

**form1.cs**

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CON.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("alter table SAMPLETABLE add "+dateTimePicker1.Text + " VARCHAR[50]", CON);
        SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CON.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
```

When run the program, which showing an error

> "The definition for column Thursday' must include a data type."

Comment: Be aware of the SQL injection issue in you code.

Comment: Replace square brackets to parentheses: `varchar(50)`.

Comment: Bad luck,Still have the same error @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: I see quotation mark after the Thursday. This is the reason of error. Next time show the complete error message!

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The definition for column 'Thursday' must include a data type.@AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column to your DataTable first.

```
DataColumn myColumn = new DataColumn("ColumnName",System.DateTime);
```

Then fill... [How to Bind specific Columns of a datatable to a datagridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907429/how-to-bind-specific-columns-of-a-datatable-to-a-datagridview)

Then insert the column in the beginning of your table:

```
myTable.Columns.Add(myColumn);
myColumn.SetOrdinal(0);// to put the column in position 0;
```