# c# bind DataGridView to IEnumerable<XElement> from LINQ to XML filtered results

Tags: c#, xml

My XML looks like this

```
<root>
<record>
 <Object_Number> 1</Object_Number>
 <Object_Level> 1</Object_Level>
 <Object_Heading> Introduction</Object_Heading>
 <Object_Text> </Object_Text>
 <Milestones> </Milestones>
 <Unique_ID> </Unique_ID>
 <Field_type> Info</Field_type>
 <SG_attribute> </SG_attribute>
<Object_Identifier>1</Object_Identifier>
<Object_URL>doors://D1DDBAPP04:36677/?version=2&amp;prodID=0&amp;view=0000001a&amp;urn=urn:telelogic::1-432aa0956f684cff-O-1-00028f60</Object_URL>
</record>
...
records...
...
</root>
```

Is it possible bind a IEnumerable result to a DatgridView and automatic detect columns?

Initially, I've done this

```
ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(myXml);
```

Then, convert to a DataTable

```
dt = ds.Tables["record"]
```

And this can directly populate DGV

```
dgvDoors.DataSource = dt;
```

But now, I realize that it's more easily to manipulate data directly in XML (with LINQ) and need somehow to display that (filtered) results in DataGridView

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xdoc.Element("root").Elements("record");
```

Now is it possible to display 'elements' to DataGridView and detect columns such in original XML?

Thank you,

PS.

```
var bs = new BindingSource { DataSource = elements};
dgvDoors.DataSource = bs;
```

This is not working correctly since instead of records, DGV will display some other columns such as
FirstAttribute
HasAttributes
HasElements
...

Comment: You can try binding your IEnumerable data via Binding Source.
Here you can see example of use of BindingSource with columns specified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907429/how-to-bind-specific-columns-of-a-datatable-to-a-datagridview

Comment: It is not working, see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it working properly I would recommend converting your xml data to strongly typed View Models.

```
public class RecordViewModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Milestones { get; set; }
}
```

Below implementation, please let know if it works as you expect:

```
var elements = xdoc.Element("root").Elements("record")
            .Select(e => new RecordViewModel
                             {
                                 Number = e.Element("Object_Number").Value,
                                 Level = e.Element("Object_Level").Value,
                                 Heading = e.Element("Object_Heading").Value,
                                 Milestones = e.Element("Milestones").Value,
            });

var bs = new BindingSource 
{ 
    DataSource = elements
};

dgvDoors.DataSource = bs;
```

The conversion between Xml Data and ViewModels above is not checking for nulls, so you can move the implementation to some mapper, where the logic of converting Xml data to ViewModel would be more complex.

Comment: Yes sir! It works just perfect. I guess I don't need any check since I already validate XML against XSD schema. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try following which matches your request

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string[] columnNames = doc.Descendants("record").FirstOrDefault().Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToArray();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (string col in columnNames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
            }

            foreach (XElement record in doc.Descendants("record"))
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    newRow[columnName] = (string)record.Element(columnName);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```