# DataGridView - Seperately change width for different columns after binding a datasource

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winforms, datagridview

I have a basic datagrid that uses a datasource and want to set the width for specific columns while other columns still use autosize.

The dataGridView code:

```
$script:dataGridView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;
$script:dataGridView1.Name = 'dataGridView1';
$script:dataGridView1.Size = '1235, 450';
$script:dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = '#000088';
$script:dataGridView1.ReadOnly = $True;
$script:dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $False;
$script:dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = $False;
$script:dataGridView1.TabIndex = 3;
$script:dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 16;
$script:dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = $False;
$script:dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 2;
$script:dataGridView1.Location = '13, 87';
$script:dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $True;
$script:dataGridView1.DataSource = $script:AWtable1;
$script:dataGridView1.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
$script:dataGridView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
```

Full script: https://controlc.com/5359a6e5

Using this I get an exception saying "The property "AutoSizeMode/Width" cannot be found on this object."

What do I have to change to make this work? C# code works too.

Comment: The DataGridView has not yet generated its Columns at that time. Subscribe to the Load event of your Form (e.g., `$form.add_Load({Form_Load})`) and set the `AutoSizeMode` or other properties of Columns there (e.g., add `Function Form_Load() { $script:dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = 1; }`) (you can actually inline that code in `$form.add_Load({ // code here}`)

Comment: @Jimi I just tried this but nothing seems to happen. Not sure if I have to change anything else or put the code in a different line. I updated my question to include my complete script maybe that helps identify the problem

Comment: Since the Columns are initially set to auto-size, when you disable this mode for one or more Columns, setting `AutoSizeMode = None` is not enough (the Column will retain its initial width), you also have to specify the `Width` value: you're not doing this in the `Form_Load` handler. Change in, e.g., `$script:dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::None; $script:dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 20;`  -- Note that this line: `$script:dataGridView2.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;`, is clearly wrong

Answer (score 1):

From error message I guess that you don't have precreated columns on dataGridView1.

You may turn `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` to false and create, style your columns on your own while binding them to specific DataSource column through columns property `DataPropertyName`. 
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907567/11409835

If you want `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` to remain true, you may change columns' settings after dataGridView1 had it's columns auto-created and rendered. For example you may change columns properties in `Form.Load` event.

`dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` is not visible in VS editor, so if you want to set it to false, you have to do it through code. `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` is active only when you are using DataSource property.